# How can I implement popover of UIBootstrap/AngularUI in div,span container?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using UIBoostrap module for form validation with popover messages in my app. The problem is the popover messages don't open when I skip a required input field.

That's the current code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Bezeichnung" name="fName" ng-model="selected.fName" id="fname-id" required="" popover-placement="bottom" popover-animation="true" popover="Field is required" popover-trigger="focus">
 <div class="error" ng-show="myForm.fName.$dirty && myForm.fName.$invalid">
     <div class="error" ng-show="myForm.fName.$error.required"></div>
 </div>
```

That doesn't work:

```
<div class="error" ng-show="myForm.fName.$dirty && myForm.fName.$invalid">
  <div class="error" ng-show="myForm.fName.$error.required" popover-placement="bottom" popover-animation="true" popover="Field is required" popover-trigger="focus"></div>
</div>
```

I've tried to find a solution in the web, but the only thing was to define an own directive for popover. Is this the only way to achieve the popover in a div or span container?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own validation

```
ng-show="flag"
```

when submiting

...

```
if(selected.fName === null || selected.fName === undefined){
    flag = true;
}
```

...

Comment: Yes, but I looking for a solution for popover messages :)